# Rollbar and typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, node-modules, importerror, rollbar

I'm stuck using rollbar with typescript, and their documentation is as poor as the AWS one.

I'm trying to build a reusable package, based on rollbar, and written with the latest TS version (4.2.4 as we speak)

So.. Let's dive into code parts (before anyone ask!).

In my index.ts, I import rollbar using

```js
import Rollbar from 'rollbar';
```

[as described in documentation](https://docs.rollbar.com/docs/importing-or-requiring-rollbar)

Some lines after, I just create the logger instance using a simple, dumb, new instruction:

```js
const options = {
   // [...]
}
this._logger = new Rollbar(options);
```

In conjunction with the following tsconfig, I'm able to build and publish the final package.

```json
{
    "extends": "@tsconfig/node14/tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "rootDir": "src/",
        "outDir": "dist/",
        "declaration": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
    },
    "include": ["src/index.ts"]
}
```

But, there is a but, for sure, otherwise they wouldn't be any question, when I'm trying to use the published package, I'm facing an error I'm not able to resolve.

```bash
TypeError: rollbar_1.default is not a constructor
```

That's not so strange. If I take a look at the generated JS, we can see that the import is done using importDefault, and the result is stored into rollbar_1.

```js
const rollbar_1 = __importDefault(require("rollbar"));

class Logger {
  constructor(options, context) {
    const config = {
      accessToken: '',
      reportLevel: '',
      codeVersion: '',
      environment: ''
    };
    this._logger = new rollbar_1.default(config);
  }
}
```

Here I am, here I'm stuck.

I do not know what I'm looking for, and have no idea about the underlying error.

For those how want to help me, here is the tsconfig of the project using the package:

```json
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/node14/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "rootDir": "./src/"
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "tests"],
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

For Sean, here is the result of "require('rollbar')"

[image]

It's definitely sure, the returned value is not helpful

I emailed Rollbar support to get some help.

Comment: What does `__importDefault` look like, and what is the shape of what is returned by `require("rollbar")`?

Comment: importDefault is pretty dumb.var __importDefault = (this && this.__importDefault) || function (mod) {
    return (mod && mod.__esModule) ? mod : { "default": mod };
};
It does nothing more than a check on the exported module, and decorate it with a default if missing. Seems to be a commonJS pattern.

Comment: It seems I can't make a new Rollbar when using "import rollbar from 'rollbar'". But, if i use the old way, aka const Rollbar = require('rollbar'), it seems to work.

Comment: Yep - and the question now is, "what is returned by `require("rollbar")` that's confusing `__importDefault` - it _should result in an object that looks like `{ default: Rollbar }`, but it clearly isn't.

Comment: Post edited with details.

Comment: Hmm ... what version of `rollbar` are you using?  https://unpkg.com/browse/rollbar@2.21.1/dist/rollbar.umd.js doesn't have anything like the methods you're showing here (no `throw 'rollbar.some.string'` to be seen anywhere).

Comment: That's because the file you're looking to is not the one that is targeted by the deployed package. As you, I'm using 2.21.1 version, but the unpackaged package.json specify that the main file is src/server/rollbar.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a CommonJS build (Node.js for example) the recommended syntax is:

```
import Rollbar = require('rollbar');
```

This may look strange, combining `import` with `require`, but it is what Typescript officially recommends: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require

If it it es2015 or higher, `import Rollbar from 'rollbar'` should work. Make sure to set `esModuleInterop` in your tsconfig. https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#esModuleInterop

Comment: It's working. After a short talk with the rollbar team, they've updated their documentation (and provided the same answer)